# 'neat' way to double append in jQuery

Tags: jquery, append

I need to do a certain action in jQuery, and i was wondering how I could do this more 'neatly', so to speak.

Let's say i have the following HTML:

```
<div id="origin">
  <a href="test" title="testtoo">Testlink</a>
</div>

<div id="target">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Now i want to append the a-tag from origin, in a li to the ul. To do this, i'd do:

```
$('#target ul').append('<li>'+$('#origin a')+'</li>');
```

However, if i do it like that, i get [Object object] rather than the link, since i'm guessing i'm trying to do 2 types in 1 line (string and object). So i usually split it into 2 lines:

```
$('#target ul').append('<li></li>');
$('#target ul li').append($('#origin a'));
```

However, i feel this method is terrible. What is the correct way to do it in 1 line, without using append twice?

(P.S. i ask this as advice to do this more neatly, i am forced in these situations to use jQuery (or javascript ofcourse), and with no acces to the HTML/CSS files)

Comment: What do you mean `"i get [Object object] rather than the link"`? Do you mean the return result for the `append`? Are you trying to use that somewhere else?

Comment: @musefan - concatenating a string with an object gets you `[Object object]`

Comment: @adeneo: Ah yes, so the single line method doesn't actually work in the first place. Still, I am not sure it's a valid question :/

Comment: What is your issue with using `append` twice? Why is that not acceptable?

Comment: @musefan - no, `'<li>'+$('#origin a')+'</li>'` wouldn't work at all, as that would give you `<li>[Object object]</li>`. As for the second example with appending twice, that's fine but the second append targets all LI's in the UL so it's not very accurate, and actually works because the append ends on the last element in the collection, but it does append to all LI's in the UL before getting there, so it's really not very efficient, unless there's only one LI.

Comment: Ah sorry, indeed to clarify: The single line approach doesn't work, so i use the 2 line approach. However, i know append is a somewhat intensive method, and to use it twice for an example like this feels really unnecessary. That's what i mean with a more 'neat' approach. Especially if i have to use this in a loop with a lot of elements.

Comment: @adeneo: Yeah I noticed that potential bug, but there are other ways to append twice, I was asking what is wrong with using it twice in general, not specifically what is wrong with using it twice the way the OP has done

Comment: @musefan - There's nothing wrong in using it twice, I do it all the time, and jQuery's version of `append` can be nested, multiple elements can be appended by seperating them with commmas etc. the possibilities are almost endless, so it's a great method.

Comment: @adeneo: Yeah I know there is nothing wrong with using it twice, and like you I would chain the appends. Or take the result from the first append if I wanted to re-use it. I am just trying to work out why the OP has such a problem with using it twice

Comment: @Mortaza: Why do you think it's so "intensive"? Is this a performance question?

Comment: [This JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/double-append) suggests that the double append is more efficient than the answer you accepted. **WARNING**: running that perf will create a long list of html on the page, it's not a problem you just need to scroll down once it's finished to see the results (it only takes a few seconds to complete)

Comment: @musefan This was a question of how to write properly, and i felt my method was too flimsy and intensive, especially if used multiple times in the same document. Your JSPerf is quite suprising for me. It might be better to use .append().append() indeed, however this method is still 1 line and shorter, which is better than mine as well :)

Comment: @Mortaza: The number of lines means nothing! Readability should come first, and then performance (unless massively poor performance in which case that would trump readability). If it's more readable for something to be on 10 lines rather than on 1 line, then I would take 10 lines every day. Number of lines becomes even less important if you use a minimizer for production script

Comment: @musefan - Try appending the elements to the right parents using the given code -> http://jsperf.com/double-append/2

Comment: @adeneo: urgh, sorry I haven't used JQuery in production for quite some time, I'm very rusty. [Try this one](http://jsperf.com/double-append/3)... your turn ;-) (yes, I know that isn't technically 2 appends!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the LI as a jQuery element

```
$('#target ul').append( 
    $('<li />', { html : $('#origin a') })
);
```

Comment: I would argue that is "less neat" than 2 lines, should I downvote?

Comment: I did not know this method existed, and after looking into it i see you can use it for all sorts of extra information (id, href, title, etc.). So i'll use this :) Thank you.

Comment: @Mortaza - Yes, creating the element the jQuery way lets you define any attribute or jQuery method in the object, even `css` etc. can be set while creating the element so you don't have to chain on methods later

Comment: @musefan neat is not the less lines of code you have but how readable it is, you can if you want put everything in a single line but it won't be as readable.

    $('#target ul').append( $('<li />', { html : $('#origin a') }) );

Comment: @ClaytonC: Yeah, the 2 lines (I think) I was referring to (2 years ago) are the ones in the OP which are a lot more readable that this answer. I am certainly not saying that less is always better

Answer (score 0):

You can get the outerHtml of anchor element and concatenate along with li element while appending:

```
 $('#target ul').append('<li>'+$('#origin a')[0].outerHTML+'</li>');
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is how I have done it before. it's not short but it's readable

```
$('<li>')
    .html($('#origin a')
    .appendTo($('#target ul'));
```

You can compress it to a single line but I like to spread it out like so to have everything laid out infront of me and make it very easy to read. Compressed will look like this

```
$('<li>').html($('#origin a').appendTo($('#target ul'));
```